# Minikube NGINX Unable to connect to the remote server

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, minikube

i have installed and run minikube on my NUK for testing purpose.
Im trying to expose an nginx instance running on a POD so that it can be reached from another PC on the same network. My network is exposed with DMZ and port forward, i tested it successfully using ssh.

If i execute a curl from the same machine, i get the welcome nginx message. From another machine on the same local network the nginx instance is unreachable.

this is my actual state:
[image]

`minikube tunnel` wont work, maybe im missing some configurations or nodeport is not the correct way?